# function toggle_visibility(id) doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript

I have a problem. Function work almost perfect but doesn't close the active div by click this div button. For example I click button1 and I want to close it by click another time in button1. Other combinations work ok. Anybody help?

```js
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    var myClasses = document.querySelectorAll('.party1'),
    i = 0,
    l = myClasses.length;

    for (i; i < l; i++) {
        myClasses[i].style.display = 'none';
    }

    if (e.style.display == 'block') e.style.display = 'none';
    else e.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
.button1 {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100px;
    background: #c1a35f;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    font: 15px Kurale;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style:none;
    margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
}
.button2 {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100px;
    background: #c1a35f;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    font: 15px Kurale;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style:none;
    margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
}
.button3 {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100px;
    background: #c1a35f;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    font: 15px Kurale;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style:none;
    margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
}
.party1 {
     display: none;
}
```

```html
<p class="button1" onclick="toggle_visibility('1')">Show/hide1</p>
<p class="button2" onclick="toggle_visibility('2')">Show/hide2</p>
<p class="button3" onclick="toggle_visibility('3')">Show/hide3</p>

<div class="party1" id="1">some text 1</div>
<div class="party1" id="2">some text 2</div>
<div class="party1" id="3">some text 3</div>
```

Comment: id's must be unique in valid HTML

Comment: as @JaromandaX mentioned, you've got 3 id's with the same value. must always be unique

Comment: If you have duplicate `id`s, `document.getElementById(duplicateId)` will return only the first match.

Comment: @Maverick Are you sure that "Other combination work ok"? I don't see how, while having duplicate IDs. And if the IDs were a matter of copy/paste typo, then I see everything working ok once fixed the dupes

Answer (score 0):

here you are

```js
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    var myClasses = document.querySelectorAll('.party1'),
    i = 0,
    l = myClasses.length;

    for (i; i < l; i++) {
        myClasses[i].style.display = 'none';
    }

    if (e.style.display == 'block') e.style.display = 'none';
    else e.style.display = 'block'

}
```

```css
.button {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100px;
    background: #c1a35f;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    font: 15px Kurale;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style:none;
    margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.box {
     display: none;
}
.bg-r {
    background-color: #c44;
}
.bg-g {
    background-color: #4c4;
}
.bg-b {
    background-color: #44c;
}
```

```html
<p class="button bg-r" onclick="toggle_visibility(1)">Show/hide1</p>
<p class="button bg-g" onclick="toggle_visibility(2)">Show/hide2</p>
<p class="button bg-b" onclick="toggle_visibility(3)">Show/hide3</p>

<div class="box bg-r" id="1">some text 1</div>
<div class="box bg-g" id="2">some text 2</div>
<div class="box bg-b" id="3">some text 3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank You for helping but this modification work a little bite wrong too, because when i open button "button bg-r" and go to open "button bg-g" this dosen't close first button.  I want to work like that for every button: Hide by default, Show/hide (himself), Hide another button when i click other.

Comment: Please do not use **answer** for *commenting*.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry just checked I have unique ID (just wrote it bad on this site). Does not work for me just hide option like i said before. Anybody ?

```js
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    var myClasses = document.querySelectorAll('.party1'),
    i = 0,
    l = myClasses.length;

    for (i; i < l; i++) {
        myClasses[i].style.display = 'none';
    }

    if (e.style.display == 'block') e.style.display = 'none';
    else e.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
.button1 {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100px;
    background: #c1a35f;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    font: 15px Kurale;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style:none;
    margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
}
.button2 {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100px;
    background: #c1a35f;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    font: 15px Kurale;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style:none;
    margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
}
.button3 {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100px;
    background: #c1a35f;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    font: 15px Kurale;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style:none;
    margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
}
.party1 {
     display: none;
}
```

```html
<p class="button1" onclick="toggle_visibility('1')">Show/hide1</p>
<p class="button2" onclick="toggle_visibility('2')">Show/hide2</p>
<p class="button3" onclick="toggle_visibility('3')">Show/hide3</p>

<div class="party1" id="1">some text 1</div>
<div class="party1" id="2">some text 2</div>
<div class="party1" id="3">some text 3</div>
```

Comment: Please ***edit*** your original post instead of posting corrected code as an answer.